# Get current section of UITableView with Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I cannot get a Swift section. I used the code:

`var section = tableView.visibleCells (). first? .section`

But for some reason, it returns `nil`.

Comment: what are you trying to do once you have the section ?. Where are you calling this code ? we need more information

Comment: do you want to get section outside the `UITableViewDelegate` functions?

Answer (score 10):

If you want to get current section from the delegate methods of `UITableView` then use following :

```
var sectionNumber = indexPath.section
```

else you can use :

```
let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow();
var sectionNumber = indexPath.section
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is solution write this code

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell? {
NSLog("Index Path Section %d", indexPath.section)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try this (Swift 3):

```
var section = 0
if let index = tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows?.first?.section {
   section = index
}
```